# Excel Macro - To compare the Excel files

Tags: vba, excel

Want to compare the two excel files, below is the code and I'm facing the following error:

> 'Type mismatch Error'.

Could you please help on this

```
Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Files()
    Dim Ab As Integer, AbName As Integer
    Dim F1_Workbook As Workbook, F2_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim iRow As Double, iCol As Double, iRow_Max As Double, iCol_Max As Double
    Dim File1_Path As String, File2_Path As String, F1_Data As String, F2_Data As String

    File1_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
    File2_Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2)
    iRow_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 2)
    iCol_Max = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 2)

    Set F2_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File2_Path)
    Set F1_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(File1_Path)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 2) = F1_Workbook.Sheets.Count

    For Ab = 1 To F1_Workbook.Sheets.Count
        AbName = F1_Workbook.Sheets(Ab).Name
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + Ab, 1) = AbName
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + Ab, 2) = "Identical Sheets"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + Ab, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        For iRow = 1 To iRow_Max
            For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max
                F1_Data = F1_Workbook.Sheets(AbName).Cells(iRow, iCol)
                F2_Data = F2_Workbook.Sheets(AbName).Cells(iRow, iCol)

                If F1_Data <> F2_Data Then
                    F1_Workbook.Sheets(AbName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + Ab, 2) = "Mismatch Found"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7 + Ab, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
    Next Ab
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    MsgBox "Task Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: It's not showing any Specific line Error

Comment: There is always a specific line that throws that error. If the error occurs and you go into debug mode you will see the line highlighted which throws that error. Have a look into [Excel Easy - Debugging](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) to learn the basics of how you debug a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you have declared `AbName As Integer` and it should have been declared as String:

```
AbName As String
```

Comment: I Have Changed that AbName As String, But still i'm getting the same error

Comment: @AbileshGR Try swapping all your Doubles for Long, this might also cause an issue depending on how many rows / columns you have. I've tested this with a small number of rows and columns and it works as expected.